# nsuserdefaults setobject crashes in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, nsuserdefaults

The following function crashes for me:

```
- (void) saveMessageFromUserDefaults:(NSString *) message{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //crashes here
    [defaults setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

This worked fine prior to iOS7.  Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What is the crash? Add more details.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is calling this method?  Also the crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it crash at the line that defines defaults, or at the setObject line?

The most likely reason to crash at setObject would be an invalid "message" object. Set a breakpoint at the line that's crashing and examine self, message, etc.